# How to disable hover effects on outer div when hovering over inner div?

Tags: html, css, hover

I have an outer div with hover effects and a button inside. I am trying to disable the hover effect on the outer div when I hover over the inner button but am failing to do so.

```css
.container {
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.container:hover {
  border: 1px solid #99ffcf;
  background-color: #bababa;
}

button {
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 170px;
}

button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button type="button">Click Me!</button>
</div>
```

Codepen Demo:
https://codepen.io/sherbethead/pen/LYMboRG

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a CSS only solution you can do so by replacing the container:hover by the below block

```
.container:has(:not(button:hover)):hover{
  border: 1px solid #99ffcf;
  background-color: #bababa;
}
```

However do note that :has is not universally supported by browers, so please check it is supported by the browsers you need over on [Can I use](https://caniuse.com/css-has)

```css
.container {
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  margin:0 auto;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.container:has(:not(button:hover)):hover{
  border: 1px solid #99ffcf;
  background-color: #bababa;
}

button{
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 170px;
}

button:hover{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button type="button">Click Me!</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yue can add `.container { pointer-events: none; }` and `button { pointer-events: auto; }`:

```css
.container {
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.container:hover {
  border: 1px solid #99ffcf;
  background-color: #bababa;
}

button {
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 170px;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button type="button">Click Me!</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but im trying to get the main div to have the hover effects, and then for those effects to go away when I hover over the button

Comment: Sorry, I thought the opposite ((